# Structure PHP application for easy upgrade and scaling?

Tags: php, deployment, upgrade, scalability

I'm having a big problem trying to find a way to structure my application for scaling. Below is my current setup:

We have an application written in PHP and MySql. The app is written in such a way that it can, in theory, serves thousands of different websites using the same codebase (but each will have different database).

1. In our current setup, we have **1 nginx config file per 1 website**, all of them pointing to the same location lets say /var/www/current-version. We have a way for us to know which website is supposed to be rendered.
2. Each time we upgrade, we update code to /var/www/new-version
3. Copy all code from /var/www/current-version/ to /var/www/old/
4. Point all current projects from current/ to old/ by search and replacing all nginx config files and the do a service reload
5. Copy code from new/ to current/
6. Loop through the websites to

   - edit the corresponding nginx config file to point to the current/ folder
   - sync the new updated config files across all instances
   - run update script (we have to do this because the upgrade process may involve migrating db and several other things)

This upgrade process involves quite a few steps and is subjected to certain issues such as when the sync does not happen fast enough.

I wonder if there is any better way to do this?

PS:
I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask this kind of question, stackexchange has too many sub-sites and I'm confused. Anyhow, please feel free to let me know if I post in the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

Why not just to use symlinks? For example, all nginx configs are set up to  /var/www/website, that is a symlink to /var/realdir/website_1_1_0. You deploy a new code to /var/realdir/website_1_2_0 and after it just change a symlink to point to this new directory.

Comment: It's a simple yet brilliant idea. However I do have 1 issue: We have thousands of sites using the same code base, yet when we upgrade we cannot simply upgrade them all at once (thus we cannot simply switch all code at once), we have to do one by one because there are chances that we have to run db migration on each site.